ASP.NET C#: Swagger не может обработать два метода контроллера с одинаковым путем
Есть два метода контроллера с одинаковым путем. При этом у этих методов есть атрибут реализующий интерфейс IActionConstraint, который в зависимости от значения query параметра перенаправляет запрос на один их них. Однако Swagger не может обработать такую маршрутизацию и выдает ошибку. Как можно принудить его учитывать этот пользовательский атрибут?
Методы контроллера:
[HttpGet("my-route")]
[Terminal("Terminal 1")]
public IActionResult UseTerminal1()
{
    // Логика 1
    return Ok();
}


[HttpGet("my-route")]
[Terminal("Terminal 2")]
public IActionResult UseTerminal2()
{
    // Логика 2
    return Ok();
}

Мой атрибут, управляющей маршрутизацией:
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public sealed class TerminalAttribute(params string[] terminalNames) : Attribute, IActionConstraint
{
    #region Реализация IActionConstraint.
    /// <inheritdoc />
    public int Order { get; }


    /// <inheritdoc />
    public bool Accept(ActionConstraintContext context)
    {
        bool accept = false;

        string currentTerminalName = context.RouteContext.HttpContext.Request.Query["terminal"].ToString();

        foreach (string terminalName in terminalNames)
            accept |= terminalName == currentTerminalName;

        return accept;
    }
    #endregion
}

Что выводит Swagger:


Почему не использовать один и внутри него произволить ветвление? Вам Swagger на оба метода нужен или только на один из них? Почему не использовать REST-подобные пути? .../terminal/1, .../terminal/2? Вроде для REST API параметры в query это не модно. С точки зрения клиента ведь совершенно фиолетово, каким образом в путь засунуть нужный параметр.

@aepot, без разницы как в Swagger будет отображаться один или два. Дело в том, что этот метод уже используется для двух разных терминалах. Изначально они оба обрабатывались в одном методе. Но сейчас появилась необходимость расширить функционал (терминалов стало больше). Будет очень большое ветвление. Именно поэтому решил вынести в отдельные методы каждый терминал

Ну раз без разницы, напишите над всеми кроме одного метода [ApiExplorerSettings(IgnoreApi = true)]

Добавь это в DI и все будет норм:
services.AddSwaggerGen(config => config.CustomSchemaIds(x => x.FullName))


Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять более развёрнутые ответы. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit].
